# Let $x \in \Bbb{R}$. Prove $1 \leq x \leq 2$ if and only if $1 \leq x \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, interval-arithmetic

The title is self-explanatory. How would I go about proving "$1 \leq x \leq 2$ if and only if $1 \leq x \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$"?

Comment: If your $n$ need not to be the "unique smallest" such number, $n=1$ works for all $1\le x\le 2.$ Otherwise use the well ordering property of nalural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$2=1+\dfrac{1}{1}$ and $1+\dfrac{1}{n}\leq 2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, but how do I prove that $1+ \frac{1}{n} \leq 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If there were some $n$ for which $1+\dfrac{1}{n}>2$, then $\dfrac{1}{n}>1$ for that $n$ which is an impossibility.

Comment: Or note that $n\geq 1$ so $\dfrac{1}{n}\leq 1\Rightarrow 1+\dfrac{1}{n}\leq 2$.